# Creating a dropdown list from SQL query in R & R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to R and R Shiny but I have a SQL query running into an R Shiny dashboard. I need to use the data that comes through from this query to have a distinct list of US States that populates a drop down box on a tab in the main body of the dashboard.

I have extracted the part of the code that I have so far to try and create this but am not having much luck at the moment. I'm wondering if I am going about this the correct way?

For the purpose of this the State_data DF is the output from the SQL query, where I need to extract just the list of states.

Thanks in advance

```
    ui <- dashboardPage(    

    tabPanel("State Level Detail",
                      fluidRow(
                          box(tableOutput("State_tbl")),
                          box(uiOutput("States_List"), plotlyOutput("State_Map"), plotlyOutput("State_Chart")))    

)
    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

          output$States_List <- renderUI({
            selectInput("STATE", "Select State", choices=States_List(), width = 350)
          })

              output$States_List <-

                renderTable({

                  validate(
                    need(State_data(),""))

                  States_List <- State_data[c("STATE")]

                })

        })

        shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The main error I get when using the above syntax is:

```
Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution for getting a dropdown with the state names, or anything else, that you read from a file.  I needed to simulate reading your file.

```
ui <- fluidPage(      
  tabPanel("State Level Detail",
           fluidRow(
             selectInput("stateAbbr", "Select State:",'')        
)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  # Simulate reading of state abbreviations  
  statesList <- data.frame (abbr='AK',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  statesList <- rbind(statesList,'AL')
  statesList <- rbind(statesList,'AR')

  # Set up the selection for states
  selectionStateAbbr <- sort(unique(unlist(statesList$abbr)))
  updateSelectInput(session, "stateAbbr", choices = selectionStateAbbr)  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```